# Build an OLD Android AOSP

Tags: android, build, android-source

Now I can fetch the newest version of packages (repo sync) and compile them in my machine (make -j8)
I cannot find a way to fetch older version of AOSP . what parameter should I pass to repo to be able to fetch old packages and work on an old version of android (e.g ICS)

Comment: In the spirit of Google - `Why build deprecated code?` :D
Can't you fetch an earlier revision or view history or something... ?

Comment: :D haha, almost the same reason as you can find older version of virtual android devices in SDK ;). Also I may need to flush it into my old device.

Comment: Until you find a better solution, i can only recommend Genymotion.

Answer (score 2):

You should add `-b` parameter. For instance, to download the sources of Android v.4.0.1 (ICS) you can use the following command:

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.0.1_r1
```

After downloading the sources the next steps are the same. More information you can find [here](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html).